# Displaying results from a dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, xhtml

I am stuck on creating a dropdown list that is connected to another php page. I have used a sql query to list the staffNames but i need them to have the value of staffID. I have connected the page task7.php (which has a query that displays purchase information of a given staffID), so once the user clicks on a name then clicks submit, that persons order information should be displayed.Currently I am able to view the drop down list, select a name, but when i click submit the table only has field names with an empty table. HERES MY CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-
strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Prac 2 Task 9</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "twa291", ".......");
mysql_select_db("factory291", $conn)
or die ('Database not found ' . mysql_error() );



?>

<form method="get" action="task7.php">
<select name="list" id="list" size="12">

<?php
$sql = "SELECT staffID, staffName FROM staff";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$title=$row["staffName"];
$id=$row["staffID"];

echo "<option value= ".$id.">".$title."</option>";

}
?>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" method="get">
</select>
</form>

<?php 
mysql_close($conn); ?>


</body>
</html>
```

HERE IS MY task7.php FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Prac 2 Task 3</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "twa291", "......");
mysql_select_db("factory291", $conn)
or die ('Database not found ' . mysql_error() );  ?>

<?php
$staffid= $_GET["staffID"];


?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT orderID, orderDate, orderDate, shippingDate, staffName FROM purchase, 
staff 
WHERE staff.staffID='$staffid'"; 


$rs = mysql_query($sql, $conn)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());

?>

<table border="1" summary="Staff Orders">
<tr>
<th>Order ID</th>
<th>Order Date</th>
<th>Shipping Date</th>
<th>Staff Name</th>
</tr>

<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { ?>

<tr>

<td><?php echo $row["orderID"]?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["orderDate"]?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["shippingDate"]?></td>
<td><?php echo $row["staffName"]?></td>

</tr>


<?php   }
mysql_close($conn); ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this would help you, but you HTML is invalid -- you have your submit button inside the closing `</select>`. Fix that and see if it helps.

Comment: Nah still got an empty table. I am so stuck its not even funny :(. Its like i got everything right but its not working. Maybe there is some kind of form name or id or select id i have to use? hmmm

Comment: Also do i need to call anything from the task7.php file? There is a $staffid=$_GET["staffID"] variable isnt that enough? (besides the coding to display the purchase details off course).

Comment: Try `$staffid = $_GET["list"]`.

Comment: That doesnt work. But what i did do is change <select name="staffID" and id="staffID"... still an empty table but now the error that says Undefined index: staffID in I:\twa\twa291\practicals\prac2\task7.php on line 16 is goone. I have posted my task7.php file above^^

Comment: Check your url after you submit. You should see something to the effect of `url.com/task7.php?staffID=something`.

Comment: wow thank you for telling me that. I realized the ".$id." was sending over staffID numbers with a full stop at the beginning and end thus the code did not recognize it and gave me an empty table. I changed it to '$id' and it works perfectly! THANK YOU SINCERELY!!!

Comment: No problem. Just be sure to answer your own question with the changes you made so that if someone comes across this later with a similar problem they know what you did.

Answer (score 0):

You have  wrapped unwanted string with `" "`

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT staffID, staffName FROM staff";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn)
or die ('Problem with query' . mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$title=$row["staffName"];
$id=$row["staffID"];
echo "<option value= '.$id.'>".$title."</option>"; 

}

?>
```

Comment: Actually, I think he intented "title" to be a variable, not text, so needs to add a dollar sign in front of the word "title".

Comment: I actually was just about to edit my code for those two errors sorry. I still get the same error at the same line

Comment: I just added the two full stops and it worked. However i am not receiving the purchase details just field names with an empty table. What could be the cause of this? Thank you

Comment: Any ideas samitha? Appreciate the help

Comment: see my code.In your code still seeing `echo "<option value= ".$id.">title</option>";`

Comment: I fixed it. I only left that because it was still working either way. Im still getting an empty table.

Comment: This is annoying ! lol :( i cant seem to find the problem! It seems like the staff id is not passing to the other page   inorder for the purcahse details to show in the table

Comment: Still an empty table :(

Comment: any ideas im extremely stuck

Comment: lol, on your processing file it should be $staffid= $_GET["list"];

Answer (score 0):

```
?php
$staffid= $_GET["list"];


?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT orderID, orderDate, orderDate, shippingDate, staffName FROM purchase, 
staff 
WHERE staff.staffID='$staffid'"; 

?>
```

Comment: you can debug and check if $_GET['list'] is actually returning something, then you can run it directly on your database sql to see if it returns a table